# Visiting Abu Simbel in Egypt for independent travellers

Tags: egypt

What are the options to visit Abu Simbel for independent travelers? Are foreigners allowed to travel there on public transport these days? Would a day trip be enough, or is there enough sights for more?

And as an alternative, are there any convenient day trips organized from Aswan? Basically I only want someone to drive us there and back, in a safe and reasonably comfortable way. Is it better to organize it through a hotel or a tour agency?

Answer (score 5):

The road down there from Aswan is considered high risk, and [currently inaccessible to foreigners travelling in their own car](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Abu_Simbel).  However, you can travel there in police-escorted bus convoys, OR rent a car with a driver from a local travel agency in Aswan, who is familiar with the roads and rules.

There's at least one daily convoy a day, and takes three hours to get there.  So once you've got your transport sorted, you'll want to choose one.  If possible, **you want to get there before sunrise**.  This isn't always possible depending on the time of year, but if you can, as soon as the bus stops, RUN, and don't stop running until you get to the site.  Take your outdoor photos of the sun rise hitting the temple FIRST before the hordes of other tourists get there, and THEN go inside to explore :)

Apparently it's also possible to go by cruise ship through the lake, but I have no more information on that :/

It's a beautiful site, and my highlight of Egypt (yes the pyramids are great, but this site is magnificent). Don't skip it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that, the road itself is dangerous for the fact that you are driving between mountain and deserts, otherwise you are going to one of the most safe places according to its value and history to Egyptians so the government making sure these kind of tourist places are safe for tourists to visit and as well as safe from any harm or illegal activity.

I am Egyptian. Back when I was 16 years old I used to drive this road with my uncle we used to send car tires to this side of the country was a lot of fun actually.

Note: Very dangerous to drive at night for someone unfamiliar with the road; thousands of accidents annually on this road.